# How to handle browser bugs?

Tags: browser-bugs

I'm constantly running into browser bugs. So much that I spend more time on finding workarounds, than on normal work. At first, I started to ignore IE6. And then IE7, IE8, IE9, Opera Mini, then recently Opera and IE10 as well. Now all I focus on are these: Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Edge, Android Browser, iOS Safari. Much better now, but it's still a nightmare, all I see is inconsistent behaviour, small but annoying bugs etc. What's wrong with this? Simple. My customers do not pay for this, instead they blame me if something is messed up by a browser.

- **Is there a web developer technique that makes it easier/faster to
  deal with browser bugs?**
- **Maybe a workaround collection site, or an automatic "validator" that highlights problematic codes and suggests fixes?**
- **Or something that I can't even think of?**

What I have tried already:

- Filing bugs: my customers don't wait for the fixes to come.
- Work on workarounds: my customers don't pay enough for this.
- Ignore even more browsers: my customers think I'm an amateur.
- Find a market that is financially stronger than the poor and small Hungarian companies: in process.

Comment: A good option is to choose a framework with excellent cross-browser compatibility. Perhaps you will be lonely not writing your own HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but the benefits are significant.

Comment: Good idea. Previously I had learnt jQuery, experimented with CodeIgniter and things like that, but I've decided to write pure JS and my own PHP instead, to understand the code better and be less dependent. I will reconsider it.

Comment: Re: `Maybe a workaround collection site` , not a workaround collection site but maybe you can use http://caniuse.com to check what is the status of support for a feature before you code with it, so you can better decide if you still want to code with it or not, instead of coding it and then finding out Oh it doesn't work in this or that browser, I just wasted X hours on this...

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now. :) I would pay for a tool (or an extra caniuse service) that works this way: you select the browsers you want to support, then download a browser extension that periodically checks the currently developed code, and alerts you if you try to use something unsupported. Do you know about something similar, so that I don't need to type all the things in the caniuse search field? Currently this is slooow.